# Writing to servlet stream

Tags: java, http, stream, io

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible, it might not. Here is my problem:

I'm trying to use a Servlet to pass information from a client to a server via HTTP. This communication is very frequent (I'm passing UI information, so every single mouse event), so I want to have as little overhead as possible to avoid latency issues, which is why I would like to not do a GET call for each transmission. HTTP is a requirement. I'm using an older Tomcat version (Servlet API 2.4). I guess this is somewhat of a web sockets use case, but I don't have any web sockets support available.

What I tried was to open a URL connection on the client side, and to open the input stream (otherwise the doGet() of the servlet never gets called). I'm passing an argument for initialization purposes to the client.

```
URLConnection uiConnection = url.openConnection();      
uiConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encode("xyz" + ":"
            + "xyz"));
uiConnection.setReadTimeout(0);
uiConnection.setDoOutput(true);
uiConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(
uiConnection.getInputStream());
```

When I later try to retrieve an ouput stream from this connection, I'm getting a ProtocolException (cannot write output after reading input).

```
out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
uiConnection.getOutputStream()));
out.write(uiUpdate);
```

On the servlet end I did something like this:

```
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(
            request.getInputStream());
```

Am I completely on the wrong track or is something like this possible without using a new connection for each transmission?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: IMO you're trying to make a servlet do something it doesn't want to do, and wasn't designed to.

Comment: I agree with @DaveNewton - the only way I can think of to avoid sending a new request for each event is to roll you own HTTP Client at the socket level, that allows you send a request using [Chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), so each event can be send as a chunk in a live manner. Even then, the server will have to be capable of processing part of the request before it has received all of it. Why `HTTP is a requirement`? Is there absolutely no way around this?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The firewall will only allow traffic through port 80. I guess technically it doesn't necessarily mean HTTP, but the transport protocol needs to have a HTTP friendly handshake (like for instance Web Sockets). I'm not quite sure how web sockets are implemented, but I wonder if whatever they are doing may help with finding another workaround.

Comment: Dave and Dave may be right in a perfect world. The solution you have arrived works fine and the trick to use a servlet container to get through the firewall is not bad.

Comment: Well, my current solution actually doesn't work. I'm not getting past the ProtocolException (see above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key question for this, is do you also have http traffic going to this IP?  If so, there may not be anything you can do using just java.  If not, then create a servlet to listen in on port 80, and parse the incoming data directly.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: Thanks. That information was indeed missing. There is other HTTP traffic to this IP.

Comment: @Mark: then I don't think this will work without opening a new connection for each transmission.  Its possible that you might be able to write something for Tomcat to do this, and of course both Tomcat and Apache are open source...